# Error in invoking Java libraries in maven Robot framework project

Tags: selenium, robotframework, maven-plugin

I have made a maven project. I am trying to run robotframework testcase. When i run through mvn robotframework:run, it runs all the testcases. Is there any way to run a single test case in robotframework maven except from adding the test in POM file.

I have also tried to run through 
robot -t testcase testsuite.robot
but it gives no keywords with name "Go" found.
Also i tried 
jython -m testcase.robot
, it also gives the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it it is possible. According to [the documentation](http://robotframework.org/MavenPlugin/run-mojo.html), you can do it like this:

```
mvn robotframework:run -Dtests=testname1,testname2
```

Or execute only certain tests based on tags:

```
mvn robotframework:run -Dincludes=tag1,tag2
```

Attention, this references the tests and/or test tags, not the files themselves.